# Need help writing a function to determine how many children a binary tree array has

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

For my CSCE 230 class, I am writing a program that deals with binary tree arrays and part of our assignment is to write a function that determines whether or not the tree is balanced. For those that don't know, for a tree to be balanced the heights of the left and right subtrees cannot differ by more than 1. She and I would both prefer the function to be recursive, but it by no means has to be.

We aren't allowed to use nodes in this program, and my teacher provided us this method of knowing where each child is supposed to be stored:

> The root of the tree is at index 0.
>
> The array that stores the values in the tree is called `values`, we are using `values.length` to represent its length.
>
> Assuming a node is located at index n, its left child is at index 2n+1 and its right child is located at index 2n+2.
>
> We are using "" to indicate that a node does not have a left and/or right child.

Assuming I have stored everything correctly, what could be causing the function below, which is supposed to measure the height of a subtree (including the root of the subtree) to return an incorrect answer?

```js
/**
 * Determines if the tree is balanced. A tree is balanced if a 
 * node's left and right subtree heights differ by at most one.
 * @return True if balanced, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean isBalanced() { 
    boolean balanced = false;
    if (values[0] == null) balanced = true;
    // count non-null subchildren for all nodes. Use P-L-R format (parent-L-R)
    // then for all non-leaf nodes, subtract the larger from the smaller.

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] != "") System.out.println("values["+i+"] has " + getNonNullSC(i) + " non-null children.");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            if (Math.abs(getNonNullSC(i)-getNonNullSC(j)) >= 0 && Math.abs(getNonNullSC(i)-getNonNullSC(j)) <= 1)
                balanced = true;
        }
    }

    return balanced;
}

// returns the number of non-null children a subtree has
private int getNonNullSC(int a) {
    int count = 0;
    if (a+a+2 < values.length) {
        if (values[a] == null) count = 1; // if it is a leaf node, it has no children
        else if (values[a+a+1] != null) { // if it has a left child
            if (values[a+a+2] == null) count = 2; // it has one child if no right child
            else count = 2; // otherwise it has two children
        }
        else if (values[a+a+2] != null) { // if it has a right child
            if (values[a+a+1] == null) count = 1; // it has one child if no left child
            else count =  2; // otherwise it has two children
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Let's (have you) debug this a bit: grab a pen and some paper, take a very short tree, and check what happens at each line, rather than what _should_ happen. (writing it on paper makes a difference here, it forces your brain to not make assumptions and skip over what it assumes already words). It should be pretty easy to find two very short trees like `a(b,c)` and `a(b,c(d(e)))` and then start writing)

Comment: Hmmm, if this is supposed to be recursive I'm not seeing some fundamental pieces needed to achieve that. Pieces such as a self call and a combination of it's primary parameter (in this case that would seem to be a summation of the `count` value).

Comment: It's not required to be recursive.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you've forgotten to include the root at some point.

An easy check sanity check is to remember you have 4 cases:
Case 1: the node doesn't exist, so count = 0
Case 2: the node has no children, so count = 1
Case 3: the node has one child, so count = 2 (because you said we're including the root)
Case 4: the node has two children, so count = 3.

At no point does your code return a 3 because you've forgotten to include the root.

Also, this method will always have a maximum of 3, so you may want to revise the method to call itself recursively for each child node if you want to know the number of nodes for the entire tree.

A side note, you check for the left and right nodes twice. You could simplify your code to look something like this since we don't care which node is counted first:

```
private int getNonNullSC(int a) {
int count = 0;
if (a+a+2 < values.length) {
    if (values[a] == null) 
    {
        count = count + 1; // Or simplified: count++; which means count is now 1
    }

    if (values[a+a+1] != null) {
        count++; // which means counts is now 2
    }

    if (values[a+a+2] != null) {
        count++; // which means count is now 3 or 2 if there was no left node
    }
}
return count;
```

}

Comment: Updated the code that was in the question, I had left out one of the other functions that could be causing the problem as well.